# Kusto: Not failing if Table does not exist

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-sentinel

I intend to design rule templates for Microsoft Sentinel using KQL **for different instances**. The workspaces have various log sources, so different tables.

Some detectoins can be made using different log sources, so different tables. For example for Logons, using `SigninLogs` for Azure AD and `SecurityEvent`.

I've designed my query as such:

```
          let AD_Rule = SecurityEvent
          | where ...
          let AAD_Rule = SigninLogs
          | where ...
          union isfuzzy=true AD_Rule, AAD_Rule
```

Problem: sometimes, one workspace has `SecurityEvent` and sometimes not. Pushing rule into the latter yields:

```
Status Message: Failed to run the analytics rule query. One of the tables does not exist. (Code:BadRequest)
```

How can I force my KQL to return an empty result instead of failing if one of the table is missing?

Answer (score 0):

*(The error message you've included doesn't come from the Kusto backend, so please take the following with a grain of salt*)

if you know a minimal subset of the schema you plan to get in the response, you can union with an empty `datatable` that has that schema.

for example:

```
union isfuzzy = true 
   NonExistingTable1,
   NonExistingTable2,
   (datatable(col_1:string, col_2:int)[])
```